# Как написать логику для TagBar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Имеется следующая конструкция:

- модальное окно `popup-window` со списком категорий (появляется при нажатии на `add-category`);
- `categories-list` - блок, куда помещаются выбранные категории.

Логика такова: человек жмет на кнопку `Add Category`, появляется модальное окно - здесь выбираются нужные категории, жмется `Choose` и отмеченные выбранными категории появляются в поле блока `categories-list`. У каждой категории блока `categories-list` есть кнопка "удалить" - т.е. нажав на неё, категория исчезает и `:checked` в модалке снимается.

Большая просьба объяснить, как это сделать, ибо `jQuery` у меня на уровне `addClass` / `removeClass`.

[Песочница](http://codepen.io/Vlastelin/pen/mRpRjg)

```js
$('.categories-list .add-category').click(function () {
  if ($('#select-category-popup').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#select-category-popup').fadeIn();
  }
});
$('.close-modal-window').click(function () {
  $('#select-category-popup').fadeOut();
});
$('.choose-btn').click(function() {
  $('#select-category-popup').fadeOut();
})
```

```css
.categories-list {
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  border-bottom: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.categories-list .category {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 6px 32px 4px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.categories-list .category.selected-category {
    background: #eeeeee;
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 32px;
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon:after {
    content: '';
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
    transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon.delete:after {
    content: '\f00d';
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    color: #aaa;
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon.add:after {
    content: '\f067';
    padding-top: 1px;
    color: #000;
}
.categories-list .category.add-category {
    background: #ffe69a;
}
.categories-list .category:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.categories-list .category.add-category:hover {
    border: 1px solid #fbbc25;
}
.categories-list .category.selected-category:hover {
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    background: #eeeeee;
}
.categories-list .category.selected-category:hover:after {
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon.delete:hover:after {
    color: #333;
}


.category-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#select-category-popup {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding: 20px;
}
#select-category-popup .close-modal-window {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.choose-btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="categories-list">
  <li class="category selected-category">
    Action
    <span class="category-icon delete"></span>
  </li>
  <li class="category add-category">
    Add category
    <span class="category-icon add"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="select-category-popup" class="popup-window">
  <a class="close-modal-window">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="select-block--container">
    <ul class="category-list">
      <li class="category-item">
        <input id="category-action" type="checkbox">
        <label for="category-action">Action</label>
      </li>
      <li class="category-item">
        <input id="category-adventure" type="checkbox">
        <label for="category-adventure">Adventure</label>
      </li>
      <li class="category-item">
        <input id="category-card" type="checkbox">
        <label for="category-card">Card</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
    
    <span class="choose-btn">Choose</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как раз хороший повод начать учить js по каким-нибудь урокам, а не просить переписывать других эти уроки здесь. Ведь если Вы не знаете то Вам можно помочь сделав за Вас или научив Вас. А это требует не малых усилий и тем более такие уроки уже есть в количестве туевой кучи .

Comment: @OlmerDale, вы глубоко заблуждаетесь, если полагаете, что я не учу js. Просто кто-то ловит все "на лету", а кому-то это дается гораздо труднее. К сожалению, я принадлежу ко второй группе. Попросил помочь т.к. если сам буду сидеть - потрачу кучу времени и не факт что сделаю, а тяжесть других задач и так гнет спину. Словом, поможет кто-то - большое ему спасибо, нет - и ладно, меня здесь и так выручали тысячу раз)

Comment: А посоветовать УЧИТСЯ тогда, когда Вы сами говорите что нифига не понимаете, это разве не помощь?)  И первая причина по которой не хочется Вам верить, это огромные рулоны реального кода! Вот если человек хочет научится, то он создает миниатюры описывающие проблемы и если у него у самого не выходит, то он эти миниатюры прикрепляет к вопросу.  А у Вас этого нет, поэтому могу ещё посоветовать начать разбираться в проблеме на примерах меньшего масштаба.

Comment: В примере действительно тот код, который необходим для сохранения требуемого функционала. Если вы пройдетесь по моим вопросам, то увидите что везде где я имею хоть какую-то "почву" под ногами, я привожу свой нерабочий код. Спасибо за совет OlmerDale.

Comment: Вот поэтому и получается что Ваш вопрос - сделайте за меня ЭТО и ЭТО и ещё ЭТО, что равно заданию. Разбейте свое задание на части, напишите минимально требующийся для воспроизведения проблемы код и для каждой части задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На Вашем коде, специально на чистом `js` и как можно понятнее -

```js
const tagList = document.body.querySelector('.categories-list');

const showSelectionTagFormButton = tagList.querySelector('.add-category');
showSelectionTagFormButton.addEventListener('click', showSelectionTagFormButton_clickHandler);

const createTagButton = document.body.querySelector('.choose-btn');
createTagButton.addEventListener('click', createTagButton_clickHandler);

function render(template){
 let element = document.createElement('div');

 element.innerHTML = template;

 let result = element.removeChild(element.firstChild);

 return result;
}

const Template = {
 tag({title}){
  return (`
   <li class="category selected-category">
    ${ title }
    <span class="category-icon delete"></span>
    </li>
  `).trim();
 }
}
function create(data){
 let template = Template.tag(data);
 let tag = render(template);

 initialization(tag);

 tagList.insertBefore(tag, tagList.firstChild);

 return tag;
}
function destroy(tag){
 uninitialization(tag);

 tagList.removeChild(tag);
}

function initialization(tag){
 tag.addEventListener('click', tag_clickHandler);
}
function uninitialization(tag){
 tag.removeEventListener('click', tag_clickHandler);
}

function fill( data ){
 for(let currentData of data){
  let tag = create( currentData );
 }
}
function clear(){
 let tags = tagList.querySelectorAll('.selected-category');

 for(tag of tags){
  destroy(tag);
 }
}

function getCheckboxData(checkboxs){
 let data = [];

 for(let checkbox of checkboxs){
  data.push({
   title: checkbox.dataset.title
  })
 }

 return data;
}

function showSelectionTagForm(){
 document.body.querySelector('#select-category-popup').style.display = "block";
 document.body.querySelector('.fa-times').addEventListener('click',hideSelectionTagFormButton_clickHandler);
}
function hideSelectionTagForm(){
 document.body.querySelector('#select-category-popup').style.display = "none";
 document.body.querySelector('.fa-times').removeEventListener('click',hideSelectionTagFormButton_clickHandler);
}


function showSelectionTagFormButton_clickHandler(event){
 showSelectionTagForm();
}

function hideSelectionTagFormButton_clickHandler(event){
 hideSelectionTagForm();
}

function createTagButton_clickHandler(event){
 let categoryList = document.body.querySelector('.category-list');
 let checkboxs = categoryList.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');

 let data = getCheckboxData(checkboxs)
  .sort( ( a, b ) => a.title - b.title )
  .reverse();

 clear();
 fill(data);

 hideSelectionTagForm();
}

function tag_clickHandler({target, currentTarget}){
 if(target.classList.contains('delete')){
  destroy(currentTarget);
 }
}
```

```css
.categories-list {
  padding: 10px 20px 0 20px;
  border-bottom: none;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.categories-list .category {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 6px 32px 4px 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.categories-list .category.selected-category {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 32px;
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon:after {
  content: '';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -o-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
  transition: all 0.4s cubic-bezier(0.2, 0.57, 0.36, 0.8);
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon.delete:after {
  content: '\f00d';
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  color: #aaa;
}
.categories-list .category .category-icon.add:after {
  content: '\f067';
  padding-top: 1px;
  color: #000;
}
.categories-list .category.add-category {
  background: #ffe69a;
}
.categories-list .category:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.categories-list .category.add-category:hover {
  border: 1px solid #fbbc25;
}
.categories-list .category.selected-category:hover {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #eeeeee;
}
.categories-list .category.selected-category:hover:after {} .categories-list .category .category-icon.delete:hover:after {
  color: #333;
}
.category-list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#select-category-popup {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  padding: 20px;
}
#select-category-popup .close-modal-window {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.choose-btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ea0959dcb8.js"></script>
<ul class="categories-list">
  <li class="category add-category">
    Add category
    <span class="category-icon add"></span>
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="select-category-popup" class="popup-window">
  <a class="close-modal-window">
    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="select-block--container">
    <ul class="category-list">
      <li class="category-item">
        <input id="category-action" type="checkbox" data-title="Action">
        <label for="category-action">Action</label>
      </li>
      <li class="category-item">
        <input id="category-adventure" type="checkbox" data-title="Adventure">
        <label for="category-adventure">Adventure</label>
      </li>
      <li class="category-item">
        <input id="category-card" type="checkbox" data-title="Card">
        <label for="category-card">Card</label>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <span class="choose-btn">Choose</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Буду разбираться. Большое человеческое спасибо, OlmerDale